# How to move a player health bar in a scrolling map game?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been having a problem with my code in python, I am using the modules pygame, random, and math. I cannot seem to be able to set the player health bar of each of the two players in the each of the player's rectangle x and y positions, meaning I need each of the player's health bars in the top left corner of the player's rectangle. The player health bars keep moving and sometimes are in random places on the map. These are the three sections of code that repesent the health bars.

I have searched the web for help, but could not seem to find anything. Also, I have tried moving the rectangle for the health bar, and making it a sprite.

```
class Camera(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, display_height, display_width):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((display_width, display_height))
    self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
    self.width = display_width
    self.height = display_height

 def apply(self, entity):
    return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)
    return entity.rect.move(health_bars(player_health,player2_health))



 def update(self):
    x = (-player.rect.x + -player2.rect.x)/2 + int(display_width/2)
    y = (-player.rect.y + -player2.rect.y)/2 + int(display_height/2)
    self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)





def health_bars(player_health, player2_health):

   if player_health > 75:
     player_health_color = green
   elif player_health > 50:
     player_health_color = yellow
   else:
     player_health_color = red
   if player2_health > 75:
     player2_health_color = green
   elif player2_health > 50:
     player2_health_color = yellow
   else:
     player2_health_color = red
   pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, player2_health_color, (player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y, player2_health, 25))
   pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, player_health_color, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y, player_health, 25))





health_bars(player_health, player2_health)
```

Comment: Are the player's co-ordinates somehow changing after the player is painted, but before the heath bar?

Comment: It would be nice if you could give us code that's actually executable. We don't want the entire thing - by no means. But it would be nice if you could isolate the issue down to a minimal working example that we can execute. Most likely, `player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y` isn't what you think they are. And you need to debug those values as Kingsley points towards. Adding a simple `print(player2.rect.x)` if it moves left to right should give you a indicator of what the value is and why it is what it is.

Comment: We have no idea where `apply()` is called and what `entity` is. Why are you doing `entity.rect.move()` when `health_bars` is in charge of drawing the rects?

Comment: You can't have two returns after each other. Return means _"exit this function and go back to where I was called"._ So `return entity.rect.move(health_bars(player_health,player2_health))` will never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a health bar sprite, a combined sprite for the combination of the player sprite and the health bar sprite, and adding pygame.rect functions like clamp_ip and contains. I also blit the health bar image onto the player image.

```
bullets1 = pygame.sprite.Group()





class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = personImg
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(person_width/2, person_height/2))
        self.angle = 0
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.player_health = 100
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0




    def update(self):
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width / 2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width / 4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * 10
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -10
        elif keystate[pygame.K_w] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2):
            self.x_change += 7
            self.y_change += 7
        #if keystate[pygame.K_d] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 10
        #elif keystate[pygame.K_d] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_a] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = -5
        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.rect.y += self.y_change
        if self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.rect.right = map_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.rect.bottom = map_height
        self.rect.contains(healthbar1.rect)
        self.image.blit(healthbar1.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        healthbar1.rect.clamp_ip(self.rect)



    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet1(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

    def modifyRotation(self):
        self.angle += 5

    def modifyRotation1(self):
        self.angle += -5

    def getRotation(self):
        return self.angle

    def getRotation1(self):
        return self.angle

class Healthbar1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        player_health = 100
        for bullet1 in bullets1:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet1, player):
                bullet1.kill()
                player_health -= 5
                break
        if player_health == 0 or player_health <= 0:
            died()
        if player_health > 75:
            player_health_color = green
        elif player_health > 50:
            player_health_color = yellow
        else:
            player_health_color = red
        self.image = pygame.Surface((player_health, 25))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.fill(player_health_color)


class Combined(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = player.rect
        self.rect.contains(healthbar1.rect)
        self.image = player.image
        self.image.blit(healthbar1.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
```